# Mutually exclusive types in a function signature

Tags: typescript

Is this possible to achieve with conditional types in TypeScript?

```
type Type1 = {
  field: string,
}

type Type2 = {
  field: number,
}

// I would like to make sure that if arg1 is Type1 then arg2 is Type2
// and vice versa
const func = (arg1: Type1 | Type2, arg2: Type1 | Type2) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: You can achieve this using function overloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could approach this, but you'll probably find it's easier to just overload the signature and be done with it.

You could use a union of tuples:

```
const func = (...args: [arg1: Type1, arg2: Type2] | [arg1: Type2, arg2: Type1]) => {
    const arg1 = args[0] 
      // Type1 | Type2
    const arg3 = args[2] 
      // Property '2' does not exist on type ...
    return;
}

func({field: 32}, {field: "hi"}) 
  // ok
func({field: "hi"}, {field: 32}) 
  // ok
func({field: 32}, {field: 2}) 
  // Type at position 1 in source is not compatible with type at position 1 in target.
```

This provides fairly descriptive error messages, but the function signature is not easy to read in my opinion.

You could go the conditional route as suggested in your original question:

```
type Exclusive<A, B, T1, T2> = 
    A extends T1
        ? B extends T2
            ? A : never 
    : A extends T2
        ? B extends T1
            ? A : never
    : never;

type ExclusiveTypes<A, B> = Exclusive<A, B, Type1, Type2>

const func = <T, U>(arg1: ExclusiveTypes<T, U>, arg2: ExclusiveTypes<U, T>) => {
    return;
}

func({field: 32}, {field: "hi"}) 
  // ok
func({field: "hi"}, {field: 32}) 
  // ok
func({field: 32}, {field: 2}) 
  // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

The signature here is even more obscure to me, and the error message is not very useful at all. It's confusing to be told that a parameter is `never`.

Or you could use overloads:

```
function func(arg1: Type1, arg2: Type2): void;
function func(arg1: Type2, arg2: Type1): void;
function func(arg1: Type1 | Type2, arg2: Type1 | Type2) {
    return
}

func({field: 32}, {field: "hi"}) 
  // ok
func({field: "hi"}, {field: 32}) 
  // ok
func({field: 32}, {field: 2})
  // No overload matches this call.
```

This is still the idiomatic way to handle polymorphic function signatures in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution but this one does not use overloads or is similar to the conditional types provided by @lawrence-witt.

```
function func<A extends Type1 | Type2>(arg1: A, arg2: Exclude<Type1 | Type2, A>) { ... }
```

You can retain the type of the first argument using a generic, then for the type of the second one, exclude the first argument's type, giving you the other constituents.

[Playground with example calls](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEYoF4oG8CwAoKUBmAlhADYAmAXFAM7ABOBAdgOYA02AvttqJLPAEwp02XIRIUoDAK4BbAEYRabLJyzYA9OqgBJKAHcA9lLJRiBANbRgBqDICGl6lNpWAFneBQCeKHdpMkAio+SCRgVwgGX39BIJCIfg0tOwZSKAA3AgBjaHTFKjtsUggs4j9oPCkGLOACAyjK6oAeAEEoCAAPYEjSYLhQqAAfeP4APgAKPwDKFpZopn5KAFEO0qlipv7EIZG5ltGASkp0gwJSAG4uLEas8bR8IjJKACJnqHY5+7EnqAAGd4Ol2uVVuX0eEle70+D3ELze7EB2BudxhP3+H3QqIk6MRwOqKO+2KhmMJcIB5yAA)